# Construct object on function ccall in Julia

Tags: constructor, type-conversion, julia, implicit-conversion

I am trying to simplify some binding to C but I am not sure if this is even possible, what I am trying to do is pass an array and expect to receive in a function so an object can be constructed by the type specified in the parameter or by ccall calling the correct convert function and initialize a struct object.

Previous code, the bindings are full of `Vector3(v...)` and `Color(c...)`, is there a way to avoid this be automatic handling?

```julia
drawline(startPos, endPos, color) = ccall((:DrawLine3D, "my_lib"), Cvoid, (Vector3,Vector3,Color), Vector3(startPos...), Vector3(endPos...), Color(color...))
drawpoint([10,10,10],[100,100,100],[155,155,155,255]) # call example
```

Is it possible to reduce the code with something like this?:

```
struct Vector3
    x::Cfloat
    y::Cfloat
    z::Cfloat
    Vector3((x,y,z))=new(x,y,z)
end
#first attempt
#trying to call the Vector3 constructor without calling explicitly
drawpoint(startpos::Vector3,endpos::Vector3,color::Color) = ccall((:DrawPoint3D, "my_lib"), Cvoid, (Vector3,Vector3,Color), startpos,endpos,color) 

#second attempt (should be the simplest way to go)
#trying to receive arrays so ccall can convert from list or tuple to Struct object
drawpoint(startpos,endpos,color) = ccall((:DrawPoint3D, "my_lib"), Cvoid, (Vector3,Vector3,Color), startpos,endpos,color)
```

Is something like this even possible in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the appropriate [conversion](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.convert). `ccall` will call this for you. I think this should do it:

```
Base.convert(::Type{Vector3}, x::AbstractVector) = Vector3(x)
```

You'll probably want to add some length checks and such, and I'd probably recommend using tuples or [StaticArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) instead of `Vector`s for efficiency's sake.

Comment: I see, thank you very much, I had read something about it but didn't think this was the way to do it, an example like this would be great to have on the C interface documentation, this greatly improved my code.